# Variable value is not replaced in remove machine file

Tags: bash, ssh

When we use single quote or double quote, variable value is not replaced in remove machine file.

What is the problem?

```
echo '${machineIP}\t${fullMachineName}\t${machine}' | \
  `ssh root@${fullMachineName} "cat >> ${hostsFilePath}"`

echo "${machineIP}\t${fullMachineName}\t${machine}" | \
  `ssh root@${fullMachineName} "cat >> ${hostsFilePath}"`
```

Expected:

```
10.10.20.30 tab machine.lab.com tab machine.lab
```

Actual:

```
${machineIP}\t${fullMachineName}\t${machine}
```

Comment: Single quotes definitely should not work.  What happens if you just run `echo "${machineIP}\t${fullMachineName}\t${machine}"` ? (use double quotes, no pipe to ssh).

Comment: Please check the formatting of your commands; markdown is interpreting your backticks as a code marker.  You can put 4 spaces before each line of code to format it correctly.

Comment: As i had said "${machineIP}\t${fullMachineName}\t${machine}" also doesn't work because it gives output as \tmachine.lab.com\tmachine.lab as output which is wrong as it contains \t instead of tab and IP is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `-e` parameter for the echo command.

```
echo -e "${machineIP}\t${fullMachineName}\t${machine}"
```

This will convert \t to <TAB> char.

From the manual:

> -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

Comment: Works fine. Co-incidently i was about to give answer but remained busy in making the changes. Thanks cb0!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help with a working answer.